# Does anyone know how to handle widget's "Long Click" event on home screen?

Tags: android-sdk-2.3

I want to implement  long click ON  one widget on home screen which leads to display a menu .
Is there any way in Android where we can handle the click events on Widgets present in Home screen of android device. 

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that this is impossible because a long click on a widget triggers the ability to move or resize it on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the an answer for the same question (I want a short click to update my widget and a long click to open an activity)

Looks like it is indeed impossible:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8b979546e32059a6